# SQL query with simple join

Tags: sql

I have table with such structure

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    [Value] INT
)
```

and want to find difference between [Value] from current to previous row with only **one join operator**. 
Can anybody help me?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you please have a try first?

Comment: The syntax looks like `t-sql` but could you post some inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what record is *previous* for given *current* one. Presuming that the *previous record* is one that is *immediately before* the current record when the table is *sorted by ID* all you need is the *analytic function* and *no joins at all*:

```
  select [Value] - lag([Value]) over (order by ID)
    from #test
```

But you have to test if your DBMS *supports* analytic functions (MS SQL, Oracle)

Answer (score 1):

```
select (t1.value-t2.value) as difference
from test t1 join test t2 on t1.id=t2.id-1
```

Could be problem if you have gaps in ID's. E.g. id=1,2,3,10,11,12

If you specify RDBMC a better solution could be suggested.